# Insert data into multiple table using linq

Tags: c#, linq

In my application I have to Tables: tblName/ tblTel

tblName---> ID (PK) & Names

tblTel----> ID (FK) & Tels

I want to Insert data into tblName and tblTel tables in one transaction like  this:

```
using (MyEntities ent = new MyEntities())
        {
            tblName tblname = new tblName();
            tblTel tbltel = new tblTel();             

            tblname.Name = txtName.Text;
            tbltel.Tel = txtTel.Text;
            TA.Adderss = textBox1.Text;

            ent.tblNames.AddObject(tblname);
            ent.SaveChanges();           
        }
```

data is added correctly in tblName but in tblTel nothing happen and it is empty.

Comment: Maybe because you don't do an `ent.tblTel.AddObject(tbltel)` ?

Comment: Try adding `ent.tblTels.AddObject(tbltel);` after/before `ent.tblNames.AddObject(tblname);`

Comment: no I'm sure because of relationship between we need only one addobject

Comment: `tblName` is not connected to `tblTel` here, you created two separate objects and haven't added one to another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is necessary to add an object tblTel in your MyEntities:

```
ent.tbltels.AddObject(tbltel);
```

Comment: Consider revising your modeling of tables ;)

Answer (score 0):

you have missed the following line of code!!

```
ent.tblTels.InsertOnSubmit(tbltel);
```

OR

```
ent.tblTels.AddObject(tbltel);
```